# Communication with running Windows service

Tags: c++, windows, service

How can I communicate with running Windows service without stopping it using native C++? I need to pass integers and strings to service and get integers and to get back integers and strings.

Currently I do it through registry, but I would like use another, faster way.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you change the service app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few options:

- [Communicate via ports](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/beginningtcp_cpp.aspx)
- [Use RPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373631(VS.85).aspx)
- [Use the file system](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chzww271(VS.80).aspx)

Comment: You can also create a COM object that is hosted in the service - but I don't have a link handy demonstrating that.